# Accessing controller's global variable in ajax returns NULL

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Hi guys I have a controller which proceses data in its index() then
assign it on a global variable.

I want this global variable to be accessed by ajax when the pages successfully loaded.

Here is what I've done in my index():

```
class Search extends Ss_controller {

 public static $q;

    public function index(){

        $k = $this->input->get(NULL, TRUE);

        $data['title'] = "Search";
        $data['page_content'] = "search_results_view.php";
        $data['logout'] = "/./ssmis/home/logout";
        $data['active_nav'] = 'Search';
        $data['k'] = $k['k'];

        self::$q = array('123','456');
        ...
```

and i have this method which will be function to be called in my ajax:

```
 public function q(){

        var_dump(self::$q );

        if(self::$q ){
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['has_data'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Success';
            $response['data'] = $this->q;

            $this->echo_response($response,200,'OK!');
        } else {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'No results returned';


            $this->echo_response($response,200,'Not OK!');
        }
    }
```

The problem is  var_dump(self::$q ); returns NULL.

How can get the value of $q i assigned in the index() of my controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up terms.
In your code `$q` is a class static variable, not a global variable - those are defined by using the keyword `global` before the var name, e.g. `global $foo`. **Note:** using `global` in 2015 is a **Very Bad Idea™** - do not do this.

Secondly, you don't seem to understand how request-response works. If you call your index method it sets this variable, but once the script completes its execution, `self::$q` no longer exists. An AJAX request isn't pixie dust, it's a regular HTTP request - a *new* request. A brand-new request to the route that calls `q()` would not have called `index()` before, so no code for setting `self::$q` was ever executed, from the AJAX request's point of view. In other words, the variable you set over the course of a single request only exists until that request has returned a response. If you want it to persist, you need to store the value of `$q` in some form of persistent storage - a database, the user's session, cookies or something like that.

Comment: Your answer was helpful. My $q would hold my search results... so I think i need to change my approach.